# Unable to persist java.sql.BLOB into oracle BLOB using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, blob, openjpa

I am trying to persist the image as a blob in oracle database(11g) using JPA(2.0)

Below is my entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyTable")
public class MyEntity implements Serializable {

@Column(name="IMAGE_BLOB")
private  Blob imageBlob;

public void setImageBlob(Blob imageBlob) {
this.imageBlob = imageBlob;
}

public Blob getImageBlob() {
return imageBlob;
}
```

}

Below is my code where am trying to set the blob

```
InputSteram fis = new FileInputStream("C://folder1/folder2/image1.jpg");
byte[] imageByteArray= IOUtils.toByteArray(fis);

Blob imageBlob = new SerialBlob(imageByteArray);

MyEntity myEntity = new MyEntity();
myEntity.setImageBlob(imageBlob ).
```

when i run the above code snippet and persist MyEntity into the database, I see all the values get properly persisted in the database except the IMAGE_BLOB column value which shows null, It dint throw any exception. I also verified that the imageBlob am trying to set is not null.

Could any one please help me with this issue.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using a Blob object instead of a byte array?

Comment: yes, i had couple of issues with byte array, one - I get class cast exception,oracle.sql.BLOB incompatible with oracle.sql.BLOB          2) I was having issues with metamodel class singular attribute in JPA. So i was told to use java.sql.Blob instead of byte array.

Comment: How are you querying to check the BLOB afterward? I assume you are verifying the length > 0?

Comment: yes, i have also checked the length of the blob which is 4930 in my case.

Comment: How about using JDBC blobs instead of vendor-specific ones? Every time I've seen a problem with Oracle and BLOBs, the solution has been to stop trying to use the Vendor-specific stuff and do it properly using JDBC. Are you using `java.sql.Blob`?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz : we have tried saving the blobs using JDBC, and it works, but we are required to use open JPA to persist blobs in oracle database. yes, am using java.sql.blob

Answer (score 0):

```
@LOB  
@Column(name="IMAGE_BLOB")  
private  byte[] imageBlob;
```

It works well and I done it in Oracle DB also. So if you get the `ClassCastException` then there will be a problem in your Java code.

Comment: I cant understand whats causing this class cast exception wen i use byte array as you mentioned above in my entity class,i have read that we face this issue when there are multiple versions of ojdbc  jars. But i have only one jar which is ojdbc6.jar. Any help would be really appreciated..

Comment: I am using openJPA as a persistence provider

Comment: I have also enabled the jpa log tracing to check if the blob is being inserted, but the insert statement does not have the Blob column(Say COLUMN4)                                                         Stack trace:  openjpa.jdbc.SQL: Trace: <t 333255645, conn 417274079> executing prepstmnt 488316187 INSERT INTO SCHEMA_WEB.TABLE (COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COL3) VALUES (?, ?, ?) [params=?, ?, ?]